# MongoDB query to find multiple embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to build my first non-trivial query with MongoDB as part of a notification system, and am trying to understand how to check that multiple embedded documents either exist matching my criteria, or don't exist at all.
(Also, I'm trying to build the query using the Spring Boot Mongo api.)

I have subscription documents which have criteria maps like this:

```
{
    ...,
    criteria: [
        { key: "order.companyId", value: "ABC" },
        { key: "order.status", value: "NEW" }
    ]
}

{
    ...,
    criteria: [
        { key: "order.status", value: "NEW" }
    ]
}

{
    ...,
    criteria: [
        { key: "order.companyId", value: "ABC" }
    ]
}
```

When a new order comes in for company ABC, I want to generate a query which matches all three of the above subscriptions. Seems like I'll need a combination of `$and`, `$elemMatch`, and `$in`, but I can't find a good example of how to piece it all together. Can anyone give me some advice on how to get started with this?

In my initial attempts I've been generating criteria like this: `Criteria.where("criteria").elemMatch(Criteria.where("key").is(key).and("value").in(value, null))` but it doesn't seem to like multiple criteria for the same attribute.

---

Making use of [dsharew's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49495717/446591), I'm now using this method to build up a list of criteria for each key/value pair:

```
private Criteria equalsOrUnspecified(String key, Object value) {
    Criteria valueMatch = Criteria.where("criteria")
            .elemMatch(Criteria.where("key").is(key).and("value").is(value));
    Criteria notSpecified = Criteria.where("criteria").not().elemMatch(Criteria.where("key").is(key));
    return new Criteria().orOperator(valueMatch, notSpecified);
}
```

and then combining them using

```
        q.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(criteria.toArray(new Criteria[criteria.size()])));
```

but this doesn't seem to be matching anything. Here's an example of one of the queries produced:

```
{ 
    "isEnabled" : true , 
    "eventType" : "order::positionUpdate" , 
    "$and" : [ 
        { "$or" : [ { "criteria" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.bolNumber" , "value" : "51166350"}}} , { "criteria" : { "$not" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.bolNumber"}}}}]} ,
        { "$or" : [ { "criteria" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.consRefNumber" , "value" : "AGVS"}}} , { "criteria" : { "$not" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.consRefNumber"}}}}]} , 
        { "$or" : [ { "criteria" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.operationsUser.id" , "value" : "janedoe"}}} , { "criteria" : { "$not" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.operationsUser.id"}}}}]} , 
        { "$or" : [ { "criteria" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.bookingUser.id" , "value" : "janedoe"}}} , { "criteria" : { "$not" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.bookingUser.id"}}}}]} , 
        { "$or" : [ { "criteria" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.status" , "value" : "NEW"}}} , { "criteria" : { "$not" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.status"}}}}]} , 
        { "$or" : [ { "criteria" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.billingCustomer.id" , "value" : "EXQUOTE"}}} , { "criteria" : { "$not" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.billingCustomer.id"}}}}]} , 
        { "$or" : [ { "criteria" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.bookingCustomer.id" , "value" : "EXBE63A"}}} , { "criteria" : { "$not" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.bookingCustomer.id"}}}}]} , 
        { "$or" : [ { "criteria" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.id" , "value" : "5849005"}}} , { "criteria" : { "$not" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "order.id"}}}}]} , 
        { "$or" : [ { "criteria" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "companyId" , "value" : "ABC"}}} , { "criteria" : { "$not" : { "$elemMatch" : { "key" : "companyId"}}}}]}
    ]
}
```

Comment: "When a new order comes in for company ABC, I want to generate a query which matches all three " why should ```criteria: [
        { key: "order.status", "NEW" }
    ]``` match the query it does not belong to company ABC

Comment: @dsharew thanks for pointing that out, I actually botched the syntax worse than you thought

Comment: it is ok, did you see my question above ^

Comment: @dsharew Some uses will want all events for a company, some will want all events of a certain type, some will want only events of a certain type for certain companies. There will also be additional criteria that users can mix and match but I was keeping my example simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ultimately needed. `criteriaMap` holds attributes of an event, for which we want to find the matching subscriptions. (It has mappings like "order.bookingUser.id" => "janedoe".) If a subscription does not specify a value for a given attribute, then it's treated as a wildcard and matches all values for that attribute.

```
public Criteria createCriteria(Map<String,?> criteriaMap) {
    List<Criteria> criteria= new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : criteriaMap) {
        list.add(equalsOrUnspecified(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }
    return new Criteria().andOperator(criteria.toArray(new Criteria[criteria.size()]));
}

/**
 * Find a subscription where {@code key} equals {@code value}
 * or where {@code key} is not present.
 */
private void equalsOrUnspecified(String key, Object value) {
    Criteria valueMatch = Criteria.where("criteria")
            .elemMatch(Criteria.where("key").is(key).and("value").is(value));
    Criteria notSpecified = Criteria.where("criteria").not().elemMatch(Criteria.where("key").is(key));
    return new Criteria().orOperator(valueMatch, notSpecified);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see you have over simplified the query on the question from what you actually need. From your comments and your note "but it doesn't seem to like multiple criteria for the same attribute.". Yes you cant use one key more than one times.

You should try something like this:

```
List<Criteria> criterias = new ArrayList<>();

criterias.add(Criteria.where("criteria.key").is(key1))
criterias.add(Criteria.where("criteria.key").is(key2)) 
criterias.add(Criteria.where("criteria.value").in(values))
```

if you need the `OR` of the above criteria you should do:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria().orOperator(criterias.toArray(new Criteria[criterias.size()]))
```

If you need the `AND` of the above queries you should do:

```
new Criteria().andOperator(criterias.toArray(new Criteria[criterias.size()]))
```

Also you can combine some of them with `AND` and some of them with `OR` to fit your exact query.